# java dxa 2.2 faling while mapping returned tridion docs json to PageModelData

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, tridion-docs, dxa2.2

We are trying to upgrade dxa libraries from 1.8, after upgrading when we run the application it fails with error

```
22:27:50.091 [http-nio-9090-exec-5] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/jsontype/PolymorphicTypeValidator] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.PolymorphicTypeValidator
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.ClassUtil.findConstructor(ClassUtil.java:587)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.ClassUtil.createInstance(ClassUtil.java:571)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.cfg.MapperConfig.typeResolverBuilderInstance(MapperConfig.java:512)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.JacksonAnnotationIntrospector._findTypeResolver(JacksonAnnotationIntrospector.java:1221)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.JacksonAnnotationIntrospector.findTypeResolver(JacksonAnnotationIntrospector.java:522)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory.findTypeDeserializer(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:1350)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory.findPropertyContentTypeDeserializer(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:1535)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory.resolveMemberAndTypeAnnotations(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:1850)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.constructSettableProperty(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:785)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.addBeanProps(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:561)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.buildBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:269)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.createBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:184)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer2(DeserializerCache.java:403)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:349)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:264)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:244)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:142)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findRootValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:476)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._findRootDeserializer(ObjectMapper.java:3915)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3781)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2115)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.treeToValue(ObjectMapper.java:2612)
    at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.graphql.GraphQLProvider.mapToType(GraphQLProvider.java:165)
    at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.graphql.GraphQLProvider.loadPage(GraphQLProvider.java:128)
    at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.impl.GraphQLContentProvider.loadPage(GraphQLContentProvider.java:195)
    at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.impl.AbstractContentProvider.getPageModel(AbstractContentProvider.java:133)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy161.getPageModel(Unknown Source)
    at c.h.k.repository.content.providers.IshContentProvider.getPageModel(IshContentProvider.java:99)
    at c.h.k.repository.content.providers.ContentService.getPageModel(ContentService.java:86)
    at c.h.k.controller.IshController.getPage(IshController.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.tridion.ambientdata.web.AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter.doFilter(AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter.java:298)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I tried to analyze it found it is failing at GraphQLProvider.java which is in dxa-tridion-provider

```
line no. 128
result = mapToType(type, pageNode);

private <T> T mapToType(Class<T> type, JsonNode result) throws JsonProcessingException {
        if (type.equals(String.class)) {
            return (T) result.toString();
        }
        return objectMapper.treeToValue(result, type);
    }
```

Any help/suggestions is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this problem by updating jackson apis to version 2.10.0, previously it was refering to version 2.8.10

```
jacksonversion = '2.10.0'

com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:${jacksonversion}
com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:${jacksonversion}
com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:${jacksonversion}
com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda:${jacksonversion}
com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:${jacksonversion}
com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-afterburner:${jacksonversion}
```